# I need to scan multiple char until "." and then print them

Tags: java

My program needs to scan  single characters until "." users inputs dot. 

Then print them like the output below

```
THE OUTPUT
Hello! I print out an acronym.
Please, enter a character:
i
Please, enter a character:
d
Please, enter a character:
k
Please, enter a character:
.
i.d.k.
```

Comment: Welcome Eemil to stackoverflow, Please show your code

Comment: I've been stuck been anytips on how doing this like If Else?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        String output = "";
        do{
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Character");
            input = s.nextLine();
            output = output+"."+input;
        }while(!input.equals("."));
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: the output comes .i.d.k.. but ill work it out. Thanks for help!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make this work with the console use:

```
System.out.print("Please, enter a character:"); //printing text to console
String input = System.console().readLine(); //reading the string
```

String to character transition: `char c = input.charAt(0);`

Work with for loops to make your code work like you want to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html